# Distributed Object on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, distributed-objects

Is there a way to use **distributed objects** on the iPhone? I think you need the *NSConnection* object which is absent in iPhone's version of **Foundation**.

I know that it is not in a public framework but I don't mind. Please don't go on about that "*rejected from the AppStore*" stuff, I know that pretty well.

Comment: I've seen a replacement framework that is opensource, sadly the name escapes me.